# Populating UITableview Section with Static and Dynamic data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I Have three section in a UITableview ie - Categories, MyAccount and Support were MyAccount and Support Section are populated with static data but the categories section is to be populated with web api response by the help of Alamofire & SwiftyJSON I am getting the result which i want but can't figure out how to populate the particular section
Here is my code...

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MenuView: UIViewController, KYDrawerControllerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var menuTableview: UITableView!

struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}
var objectsArray = [Objects]()
var categoriesArr =  [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bar:UINavigationBar! =  self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    //self.title = "Home Screen"
    bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    bar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    bar.alpha = 0.0

    objectsArray = [
        Objects(sectionName: "", sectionObjects: ["Home"]),
        Objects(sectionName: "Categories", sectionObjects: categoriesArr),
        Objects(sectionName: "My Account", sectionObjects: ["My WishList", "My Profile", "My Addresses", "My Order", "Log out"]),
        Objects(sectionName: "Support", sectionObjects: ["About Us", "Delivery Information", "Privacy Policy", "Terms & Conditions", "Contact Us", "Return Policy"])]

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    callAPI()
}
//MARK: UITabView DataSources

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!


    cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}

func callAPI () {
    //SwiftSpinner.show("Sending request..")

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.picknget.com/webservice/index.php/Home/get_all_category")
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                if let _statusCode = json["status"].string {
                    print("the ststus code is ", _statusCode)
                    if (_statusCode == "1"){
                        self.parseJSON(json)
                    }
                    else {
                        self.callAlert("Alert", _msg: "Something Went Wrong Kindly Check Your Connection & Try Agian")
                    }
                }
                //print ("json result ", json)

            }
        }.responseString { response in
            //print("response ",response.result.value)
    }
}


func parseJSON(json: JSON) {

    for result in json["category"].arrayValue {
        print("The available categories are",result["MainCatName"].stringValue)
        self.categoriesArr.append(result["MainCatName"].stringValue)
    }

    print("@@@@@@@@")
    objectsArray[2].sectionObjects = categoriesArr
    print(categoriesArr.count)

    print(categoriesArr[0],categoriesArr[1])
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
      self.menuTableview.reloadData()
    });
}
```

Any Suggestion ,
Thank you in advance

Comment: If `categoriesArr` is properly populated as an array of strings you should just be able to pass it into `sectionObjects` like this: `Objects(sectionName: "Categories", sectionObjects: categoriesArr)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir but the section is empty as the way you said to implement  --  Objects(sectionName: "Categories", sectionObjects: categoriesArr) Any Suggestion sir...

Comment: Did you try to print `categoriesArr` out to check it contains the data you want to populate to table view?

Comment: @DavidODW Yes Sir after parsing the array contains the data which i want..

Comment: Do you update `Objects(sectionName: "Categories", sectionObjects: ["\(categoriesArr)"])` to this `Objects(sectionName: "Categories", sectionObjects: categoriesArr)` like alexpls said?

Comment: @davidODW sir i have changed as per the first comment but the section result out to be display nothing..

Comment: The problem is that in Swift arrays are passed by value: when you create the Objects using `categoriesArr`, it is empty.   Any changes you subsequently make to `categoriesArr` do not affect the value in the Objects structure.

Comment: @pbasdf sir, then how to do it any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: You requested `categoriesArr` using `Alamofire` is an asynchronous process. When the program is run, the data is not yet finished store into `categoriesArr`. Maybe you can register ur class as the observer for certain notifications that will send out when the data is finished store into `categoriesArr`

Comment: Use the amended code, as per the first comment.  In your code where you load `categoriesArr`, either amend it to directly update `objectsArray[1].sectionObjects`, or (once finished) assign `objectsArray[1].sectionObjects = categoriesArr`

Comment: @pbasdf sir not working..

Comment: Can you show the code where you download?

Comment: https://jpst.it/FQri     @pbasdf Sir plz go to the link to have a look in code..

Comment: Try this: Remove `objectsArray[1].sectionObjects = categoriesArr` from viewDidLoad, and put it into `parseJSON`, just after the print("@@@@")

Comment: @pbasdf sir i really appreciate you help but this also did not show up. the categories section is still empty

Comment: @pbasdf sir i have updated the code above Please have a look..

Comment: You had a dispatch_async call to reload the table View - you still need that.

Comment: @pbasdf Sir Thank you , finally its Working...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated code which works.. Thank to @pbasdf Sir Support and guidance :)

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MenuView: UIViewController, KYDrawerControllerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var menuTableview: UITableView!

struct Objects {
var sectionName : String!
var sectionObjects : [String]!
}
var objectsArray = [Objects]()
var categoriesArr =  [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let bar:UINavigationBar! =  self.navigationController?.navigationBar
//self.title = "Home Screen"
bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
bar.shadowImage = UIImage()
bar.alpha = 0.0

objectsArray = [
    Objects(sectionName: "", sectionObjects: ["Home"]),
    Objects(sectionName: "Categories", sectionObjects: categoriesArr),
    Objects(sectionName: "My Account", sectionObjects: ["My WishList", "My Profile", "My Addresses", "My Order", "Log out"]),
    Objects(sectionName: "Support", sectionObjects: ["About Us", "Delivery Information", "Privacy Policy", "Terms & Conditions", "Contact Us", "Return Policy"])]

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)

callAPI()
}
//MARK: UITabView DataSources

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!


cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return objectsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}

func callAPI () {
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://www.picknget.com/webservice/index.php/Home/get_all_category")
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
            if let _statusCode = json["status"].string {
                print("the ststus code is ", _statusCode)
                if (_statusCode == "1"){
                    self.parseJSON(json)
                }
                else {
                    self.callAlert("Alert", _msg: "Something Went Wrong Kindly Check Your Connection & Try Agian")
                }
            }
            //print ("json result ", json)

        }
    }.responseString { response in
        //print("response ",response.result.value)
    }
}


func parseJSON(json: JSON) {

for result in json["category"].arrayValue {
    print("The available categories are",result["MainCatName"].stringValue)
    self.categoriesArr.append(result["MainCatName"].stringValue)
}

print("@@@@@@@@")
objectsArray[2].sectionObjects = categoriesArr
print(categoriesArr.count)

print(categoriesArr[0],categoriesArr[1])
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  self.menuTableview.reloadData()
});
}
```